# Example of a manifold $M$ for which $TM$ and $T^*M$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

It is well-known that if we have a "standard" smooth manifold (i.e., Hausdorff and second countable, and thus paracompact), $TM$ is isomorphic to $T^*M$. The usual argument follows from taking a Riemannian metric and using the musical isomorphism fibrewise.

What if the manifold is not paracompact? Is there an example of $M$ such that those bundles are not isomorphic? (The usual argument falls apart here.)

Comment: What do you mean by "manifold"? The standard definition is that a manifold is a locally Euclidean, Hausdorff, second countable space. This implies that it is paracompact, as you say. Unless you have a different definition, there is no such thing as a manifold that is not paracompact.

Comment: Here is one reference "[The Tangent Bundle of a Topological Manifold](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317423)" written by Richard Lashof in 1972.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter It is usual terminology to refer to a topological space which is only locally Euclidean as a manifold if we are explicitly looking for the pathologies of the lack of the other assumptions, as in this case (c.f. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54760/riemannian-metrics-on-non-paracompact-manifolds) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology))). This is clear from context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long line is a "manifold" (but not second countable) which does not admit a Riemannian metric. There are smooth structures on this thing hence there is (given a smooth structure) a notion of tangent bundle and cotangent bundle. These are weird:

The long line is one dimensional, and an isomorphism $\phi:TL\rightarrow T^*L$ would therefore induce a Riemannian metric via the formula $g(X,Y)=\pm\phi(X)(Y)$ (You will need the minus sign if $\phi_p(X_p)(X_p)<0$ for a, hence all, non-zero $X_p$). Since no Riemannian metric exists, no such isomorphism can exist.

Comment: The long line is not second countable.

Comment: @lisyarus: I don't really understand your comment. This cannot occur for Hausdorff second countable manifolds, so we need to look outside this class.

Comment: @ThomasRot Thanks in advance for the answer! When you say  $\phi_p(X_p)(X_p)<0$ for a, *hence all*, non-zero $X_p$, do you mean all non-zero $X_p$ for every $p$ or all non-zero $X_p$ in $T_pM$ only? If the latter, then I think the fact that either $g$ or $-g$ is positive-definite can be seen by defining the function $f: L \to \{1,-1\}$ given by $f(p)=g(X_p,X_p)/|g(X_p,X_p)|, X_p \in T_pM \neq 0$. It is well-defined and is continuous by local trivialitity. Therefore, it is constant, since the long line is connected. Is this correct, or am I missing some subtlety?

Comment: I meant for every $p$.  I think your argument is correct. I was thinking of the following: The long line is pathconnected. Hence over a path the tangent bundle trivializes and you can have non-zero vector fields over the path. Let $X$ be such a vectorfield. Then $\phi(X(\gamma(t))(X(\gamma(t))$ cannot be zero for any $t$. Hence the sign at the endpoints is the same.

Comment: Riemannian metric exists on long line — as it's locally $\Bbb R$, but it fails to integrate to metric, and you obviously confuse this two structures. (Particularly, tangent and cotangent bundle are isomorphic).

Comment: @xsnl: I think you are mistaken.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54760/riemannian-metrics-on-non-paracompact-manifolds

Comment: Cited answer proves nonexistence of metric structure on long line $L$. My point is that $TL$ is trivial, and, consequently, any of its tensor byproducts, e. g. $Sym^2T*$, sections of which are Riemannian tensors — and that is what we need for isomorphism of tangent and cotanget bundles, which is, by definition, a full-rank (nonzero in this case) section of Hom(T, T^*).

Comment: As $Sym^2T^*$ is trivial, it obviously has nonzero section, giving isomorphism $T = T*$, and, consequently, by adjunction, isomorphism $Hom(T, T^*) = T \otimes T$, having nonzero section as well. Whether or not there exist a metric, which is geodesic distance wrt this Riemannian tensor has zero relation to bundle isomorphism.

Comment: TL is not trivial

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-023-02/S0002-9939-1969-0246318-X/S0002-9939-1969-0246318-X.pdf